# Dar nombre de una variable por un usuario en c++

Tags: c++

Buenas días;

Solo una pregunta que llevo mucho tiempo haciéndomela. En un programa de c++ podemos declarar con un nombre a una variable de forma muy sencilla, por ejemplo:

int operando_uno;

Sin embargo, mi pregunta es si se puede dar ese nombre "operando_uno" pero que sea el usuario el que la introduzca para que posteriormente sea usada. Por ejemplo, algo así;

cout<<"intro nombre de variable";     //El usuario introduce operando_uno
/*Aquí introducir código para asignar a operando_uno un valor*/
suma= operando_uno + operando_dos;    //Ahora hacemos uso de operando_uno

Se podría hacer???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No, no se puede.

Sí, sí que se puede hacer en lenguajes que soportan reflexión.
Pero C++ no soporta reflexión. Soporta RTTI, que es un subconjunto de reflexión, pero no es suficiente para hacer esto.

#### Sí se puede desde un punto de vista funcional.

Puedes implementar esta funcionalidad de cara al usuario. La herramienta apropiada es el diccionario, std::map en C++. Trauma da un ejemplo de uso en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/77503/301). No tendrás variables añadidas al programa a nivel del código del lenguaje, sino a nivel de datos, pero esto no es importante.

#### Sí que se puede.

Con un programa que se modifique a sí mismo.

El siguiente programa permite al usuario añadir nuevas variables, asignarles valores e imprimir su suma.
Cuando el usuario introduce un nuevo nombre de variable el programa copia su propio código C++ que está en unos ficheros de plantilla y añade las líneas necesarias para las nuevas variables. Después compila el programa y ejecuta el nuevo programa substituyendo al antiguo.
El programa necesita de 4 ficheros auxiliares.
Está hecho con GNU g++ sobre linux, pero se puede adaptar a cualquier sistema.

He usado nombres de variables y funciones que empiezan por `_` para que no entren en conflicto con los que use el usuario. Pero igualmente hay nombres de variable prohibidos como `int` o `main`. Esto se detecta porque el programa no compila.

Si a alguien se le ocurre usar esta loca idea para software real debe tener en cuenta que es vulnerable a ataques de inyección C++.

El programa programa.cpp:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

// Variables definidas por el usuario

// Lista de nombres de variables
std::vector<std::string> _nombresVar;

int* _obtenerPuntero( std::string _nombre) {
    auto _it = std::find(_nombresVar.begin(), _nombresVar.end(), _nombre);
    int _pos = _it - _nombresVar.begin();
    switch ( _pos ) {
    }
}

void _componerListaNombresDeVariable() {
}

std::string _pideNombre()
{
    std::cout << "Introduzca nombre de variable:";
    std::string _nombre;
    std::cin >> _nombre;
    return _nombre;
}

void _crearCodigoCpp( std::string _nombreNuevaVar ) {
    std::ofstream _fich;

    system( "rm -f prog generado.cpp");
    system( "cat plantilla1.cpp >> generado.cpp");

    // Escribir codigo que declara las variables.
    _fich.open ("generado.cpp", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    for( auto _it=_nombresVar.begin(); _it!=_nombresVar.end(); ++_it)
        _fich << "int " << *_it << " = " << *_obtenerPuntero(*_it) << ";\n";
    _fich << "int " << _nombreNuevaVar << " = 0;\n";
    _fich.close();

    system( "cat plantilla2.cpp >> generado.cpp");
    
    // Escribir codigo para obtener un puntero a una variable. Usado por _obtenerPuntero()
    _fich.open ("generado.cpp", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    for ( int _i = 0; _i<_nombresVar.size(); ++ _i )
        _fich << "case " << _i << ": return &" << _nombresVar[_i] << ";\n"; 
    _fich << "case " << _nombresVar.size() << ": return &" << _nombreNuevaVar << ";\n"; 
    _fich.close();

    system( "cat plantilla3.cpp >> generado.cpp");

    // Escribir codigo que añade nombres de variables a la lista.
    _fich.open ("generado.cpp", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    for( auto _it=_nombresVar.begin(); _it!=_nombresVar.end(); ++_it)
        _fich << "_nombresVar.push_back(\"" << *_it << "\");\n";
    _fich << "_nombresVar.push_back(\"" << _nombreNuevaVar << "\");\n";
    _fich.close();
    
    system( "cat plantilla4.cpp >> generado.cpp");
}

void _anyadirVar() {
    std::string _nombre = _pideNombre();
    auto it = std::find(_nombresVar.begin(), _nombresVar.end(), _nombre);
    if ( it!=_nombresVar.end() ) {
        std::cout << "¡Incorrecto! Ese nombre ya está usado.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    _crearCodigoCpp(_nombre);
    int _res = system( "g++ -std=c++11 -o generado generado.cpp > /dev/null 2>/dev/null");
    if ( _res!=0 ) {
        std::cout << "No se puede usar ese nombre de variable.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    _nombresVar.push_back(_nombre);
    execl( "./generado", NULL);
}

void _asignarValor() {
    std::string _nombre = _pideNombre();
    auto _it = std::find(_nombresVar.begin(), _nombresVar.end(), _nombre);
    if ( _it==_nombresVar.end() ) {
        std::cout << "¡Incorrecto! Esa variable no existe.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    int _valor;
    std::cout << "Introduzca valor entero:";
    std::cin >> _valor;
    if ( std::cin.fail() )
        throw 2;
    int* _p = _obtenerPuntero( _nombre );
    *_p = _valor;
}

void _calcularSuma() {
    int _suma = 0;
    
    for ( auto _it=_nombresVar.begin(); _it!=_nombresVar.end(); ++_it ) 
        _suma += *_obtenerPuntero(*_it);
    
    std::cout << "Las variables suman " << _suma << "\n";
}

int main() {
    _componerListaNombresDeVariable();
    for(;;) {
        try {
            std::cout << "Elija opción y pulse INTRO:\n";
            std::cout << "1.- Añadir variable\n"; 
            std::cout << "2.- Asignar valor a variable\n"; 
            std::cout << "3.- Calcular suma\n"; 
            std::cout << "4.- Salir\n"; 
            std::cout << "Opcion:" << std::flush;
            int _opcion;
            std::cin >> _opcion;
            if ( std::cin.fail())
                throw 2;
            switch ( _opcion ) {
                case 1: _anyadirVar(); break;
                case 2: _asignarValor(); break;
                case 3: _calcularSuma(); break;
                case 4: return 0;
                default :
                    std::cout << "Opcion incorrecta\n";
            }
        }
        catch( int _err ) {
            if ( _err==2 ) {
                std::cout << "Eso no es un numero\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');            
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Fichero plantilla1.cpp :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

// Variables definidas por el usuario
```

Fichero plantilla2.cpp :

```
// Lista de nombres de variables
std::vector<std::string> _nombresVar;

int* _obtenerPuntero( std::string _nombre) {
    auto _it = std::find(_nombresVar.begin(), _nombresVar.end(), _nombre);
    int _pos = _it - _nombresVar.begin();
    switch ( _pos ) {
```

Fichero plantilla3.cpp :

```
    }
}

void _componerListaNombresDeVariable() {
```

Fichero plantilla4.cpp :

```
}

std::string _pideNombre()
{
    std::cout << "Introduzca nombre de variable:";
    std::string _nombre;
    std::cin >> _nombre;
    return _nombre;
}

void _crearCodigoCpp( std::string _nombreNuevaVar ) {
    std::ofstream _fich;

    system( "rm -f prog generado.cpp");
    system( "cat plantilla1.cpp >> generado.cpp");

    // Escribir codigo que declara las variables.
    _fich.open ("generado.cpp", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    for( auto _it=_nombresVar.begin(); _it!=_nombresVar.end(); ++_it)
        _fich << "int " << *_it << " = " << *_obtenerPuntero(*_it) << ";\n";
    _fich << "int " << _nombreNuevaVar << " = 0;\n";
    _fich.close();

    system( "cat plantilla2.cpp >> generado.cpp");
    
    // Escribir codigo para obtener un puntero a una variable. Usado por _obtenerPuntero()
    _fich.open ("generado.cpp", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    for ( int _i = 0; _i<_nombresVar.size(); ++ _i )
        _fich << "case " << _i << ": return &" << _nombresVar[_i] << ";\n"; 
    _fich << "case " << _nombresVar.size() << ": return &" << _nombreNuevaVar << ";\n"; 
    _fich.close();

    system( "cat plantilla3.cpp >> generado.cpp");

    // Escribir codigo que añade nombres de variables a la lista.
    _fich.open ("generado.cpp", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    for( auto _it=_nombresVar.begin(); _it!=_nombresVar.end(); ++_it)
        _fich << "_nombresVar.push_back(\"" << *_it << "\");\n";
    _fich << "_nombresVar.push_back(\"" << _nombreNuevaVar << "\");\n";
    _fich.close();
    
    system( "cat plantilla4.cpp >> generado.cpp");
}

void _anyadirVar() {
    std::string _nombre = _pideNombre();
    auto it = std::find(_nombresVar.begin(), _nombresVar.end(), _nombre);
    if ( it!=_nombresVar.end() ) {
        std::cout << "¡Incorrecto! Ese nombre ya está usado.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    _crearCodigoCpp(_nombre);
    int _res = system( "g++ -std=c++11 -o generado generado.cpp > /dev/null 2>/dev/null");
    if ( _res!=0 ) {
        std::cout << "No se puede usar ese nombre de variable.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    _nombresVar.push_back(_nombre);
    execl( "./generado", NULL);
}

void _asignarValor() {
    std::string _nombre = _pideNombre();
    auto _it = std::find(_nombresVar.begin(), _nombresVar.end(), _nombre);
    if ( _it==_nombresVar.end() ) {
        std::cout << "¡Incorrecto! Esa variable no existe.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    int _valor;
    std::cout << "Introduzca valor entero:";
    std::cin >> _valor;
    if ( std::cin.fail() )
        throw 2;
    int* _p = _obtenerPuntero( _nombre );
    *_p = _valor;
}

void _calcularSuma() {
    int _suma = 0;
    
    for ( auto _it=_nombresVar.begin(); _it!=_nombresVar.end(); ++_it ) 
        _suma += *_obtenerPuntero(*_it);
    
    std::cout << "Las variables suman " << _suma << "\n";
}

int main() {
    _componerListaNombresDeVariable();
    for(;;) {
        try {
            std::cout << "Elija opción y pulse INTRO:\n";
            std::cout << "1.- Añadir variable\n"; 
            std::cout << "2.- Asignar valor a variable\n"; 
            std::cout << "3.- Calcular suma\n"; 
            std::cout << "4.- Salir\n"; 
            std::cout << "Opcion:" << std::flush;
            int _opcion;
            std::cin >> _opcion;
            if ( std::cin.fail())
                throw 2;
            switch ( _opcion ) {
                case 1: _anyadirVar(); break;
                case 2: _asignarValor(); break;
                case 3: _calcularSuma(); break;
                case 4: return 0;
                default :
                    std::cout << "Opcion incorrecta\n";
            }
        }
        catch( int _err ) {
            if ( _err==2 ) {
                std::cout << "Eso no es un numero\n";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');            
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El aburrimiento es **muy malo** XD +1

Comment: @Trauma Si has sido tu. Has usado las palabras mágicas "no se puede" ;-)

Comment: Vaya genialidad.

Answer (score 3):

Respuesta corta: **no se puede**. El nombre de las variables ha de ser conocido en tiempo de compilación.

Respuesta larga: tienes que utilizar otro enfoque: usando **2** variables. Una para el nombre, y otra para el contenido.

Suponiendo que lo que se quiera introducir sean valores numéricos, es tan simple como:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main( void ) {
  std::string name;
  int value;

  std::cout << "Nombre de la variable: ";
  std::cin >> name;
  std::cout << "Valor inicial: ";
  std::cin >> value;

  std::cout << "Se ha inicializado " << name << " con el valor " << value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Y, si quieres que el usuario puede introducir **múltiples** variables, pues usas un contenedor auxiliar; por ejemplo, `std::map< >`:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main( void ) {
  std::string name;
  int value;
  std::map< std::string, int > dictionary;

  std::cout << "Introduzca UN PUNTO (.) para terminar.\n";

  while( 1 ) {
    std::cout << "Nombre de la variable: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    if( name == "." )
      break;

    std::cout << "Valor inicial: ";
    std::cin >> value;

    dictionary.emplace( name, value );
  }

  std::cout << "Mostrar variables introducidas\n";
  std::cout << "Introduzca UN PUNTO (.) para terminar.\n";
  std::cout << "Introduzca DOS PUNTOS (..) para mostrarlas todas.\n";

  while( 1 ) {
    std::cout << "Nombre de la variable: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    if( name == "." ) {
      std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
      break;
    } else if( name == ".." ) {
      std::cout << "Mostrando todas:\n";

      for( auto iter: dictionary )
        std::cout << iter.first << ": " << iter.second << "\n";

      continue;
    }

    std::cout << name << ": ";
    try {
      std::cout << dictionary.at( name );
    } catch( ... ) {
      std::cout << "SIN DEFINIR";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Si además queremos que pueda introducir *expresiones*, la cosa se sale de madre. Estamos hablando de un *interprete*. Y eso es otro tema, bastante mas amplio.

#### Moraleja

Lo que el programa hace, y lo que el programa *dice hacer*, no tienen porqué ser lo mismo. Un usuario *incauto* puede pensar que es el quien elige el nombre de las variables. Sin embargo, nosotros sabemos que eso **es falso**: todas las variables son conocidas y están perfectamente acotadas en tiempo de compilación.